# Adjust table of content depth in ConTeXt

Tags: table-of-contents, context, context-mkiv

How to create a table of contents in ConTeXt MkIV with dots? In the wiki there is

```
\title{Inhalt}
\placelist[section]
```

But the old way to make dots

```
\setupcombinedlist[content][level=4, alternative=c]
\completecontent
```

does not work anymore. I need the "level", s.t. only the section are in the toc, and the dots, both.

Comment: For further questions consider adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display dots in the table of contents you use `alternative=c`.

The `level` setting is deprecated and does not work in a current ConTeXt. You
can instead use the `list` key to decide what you want to print in
your table. By default unnumbered heads like `title` and `subject` are not
printed. Here is a complete example including custom defined
headers.

```
\setupcombinedlist
  [content]
  [alternative=c,
   list={Title, Subject, chapter, section}]

\definehead
  [Title]
  [chapter]

\definehead
  [Subject]
  [section]

\setuphead
  [Title, Subject]
  [number=no,
   incrementnumber=list]

\starttext

\completecontent

\startTitle [title=Title]
  \startSubject [title=Subject]
  \stopSubject
\stopTitle

\startchapter [title=Chapter]
  \startsection [title=Section]
    \startsubsection [title=Subsection]
    \stopsubsection
  \stopsection
\stopchapter

\stoptext
```

Result

[image: result]

As you can see, the `subsection` is not listed because it is not included in the `list` argument.